# Average over intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this data set where I'm creating a report per shift displaying a certain activity per hour. Eg.: A shift runs from 7-15, so the report will be:
7:00 - 15 moves
8:00 - 18 moves

This report contains filters for weeks and days, as the goal is for users to see their shift performance.

However, I'd like to compare the activities in a specific hour with the same hour, same day in the last 10 weeks. So for example:

I've got 15 moves in hour 7:00 of a Tuesday and i'd like to compare that with the average move count on 7:00 of a Tuesday in the last 10 weeks.

How would I get this in SQL! :-)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results in *text tables* in the question.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: "A shift runs from 7-15, so the report will be: 7:00 - 15 moves 8:00 - 18 moves" - you may have a clear idea what this means but I can barely make any sense of it. Assume that we're strangers on the internet who share *no* context with you about your organisation or requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that might get you moving in the right direction. Given that you have not stated your data structure, I have taken the liberty to assume what that may be.

You can run the following in SSMS to review/modify the results yourself.

**First, I created a table variable to simulate the assumed data.**

```
-- Create a dummy "shift" table --
DECLARE @shifts TABLE ( shift_id INT IDENTITY ( 1, 1 ) PRIMARY KEY, shift_date DATETIME, shift_moves INT );
```

**Then I inserted some dummy data. For the sake of time and simplicity, I stuck with Tuesdays over the last ten weeks.**

```
-- Insert ten weeks of Tuesdays --
INSERT INTO @shifts ( shift_date, shift_moves ) VALUES
  ( '11/06/2018 07:10:00', 5 )
, ( '11/13/2018 07:08:00', 12 )
, ( '11/20/2018 07:00:00', 14 )
, ( '11/27/2018 07:20:00', 15 )
, ( '12/04/2018 07:35:00', 12 )
, ( '12/11/2018 07:18:00', 11 )
, ( '12/18/2018 07:16:00', 10 )
, ( '12/25/2018 07:00:00', 12 )
, ( '01/01/2019 07:00:00', 13 )
, ( '01/08/2019 07:22:00', 15 );
```

The table variable @shifts now contains the following data:

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| shift_id |       shift_date        | shift_moves |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------+
|        1 | 2018-11-06 07:10:00.000 |           5 |
|        2 | 2018-11-13 07:08:00.000 |          12 |
|        3 | 2018-11-20 07:00:00.000 |          14 |
|        4 | 2018-11-27 07:20:00.000 |          15 |
|        5 | 2018-12-04 07:35:00.000 |          12 |
|        6 | 2018-12-11 07:18:00.000 |          11 |
|        7 | 2018-12-18 07:16:00.000 |          10 |
|        8 | 2018-12-25 07:00:00.000 |          12 |
|        9 | 2019-01-01 07:00:00.000 |          13 |
|       10 | 2019-01-08 07:22:00.000 |          15 |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

**I created a few parameters that you might pass to a stored procedure.**

```
-- What date are we looking at? --
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '01/08/2019';

-- How many weeks back to compare? --
DECLARE @weeks_back INT = -10;
```

***Remember:** To look backward, @weeks_back **MUST** be a negative number. *In production, you would have a check/handle for this.*

**Next, I created two local variables to help keep the date/time simple for use when querying.**

```
-- Create variables for the start and end times for simplicity --
DECLARE 
    @sDT DATETIME = CAST( CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), @date, 101 ) + ' 00:00:00' AS DATETIME ),
    @eDT DATETIME = CAST( CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), @date, 101 ) + ' 23:59:59' AS DATETIME );
```

**Then, it was a matter of querying the data for the desired results using CROSS APPLY.**

Using CROSS APPLY allows me to query a second subset of shift data that is tied to the primary record queried ( in this case a shift_date of 01/08/2019 ) for the desired time frame ( @weeks_back ).

```
-- Get resultset --
SELECT
    DATEPART( hh, shift_date ) AS [shift_hour]
    , DATENAME( dw, s.shift_date ) AS [shift_day]
    , CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), s.shift_date, 101 ) AS [shift_date]
    , s.shift_moves
    , shift_avg.shift_average
FROM @shifts AS s
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT
        AVG( a.shift_moves ) AS [shift_average]
    FROM @shifts a
    WHERE
        -- restrict to the current hour.
        DATEPART( HH, a.shift_date ) = DATEPART( HH, s.shift_date )
        -- restrict to the current day of the week.
        AND DATEPART( DW, a.shift_date ) = DATEPART( DW, s.shift_date )
        -- compare against the desired time period / weeks back.
        AND a.shift_date BETWEEN DATEADD( WW, @weeks_back, CAST( CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), s.shift_date, 101 ) AS DATETIME ) ) AND a.shift_date

) AS shift_avg
WHERE
    s.shift_date BETWEEN @sDT AND @eDT
ORDER BY
    s.shift_date;
```

Which returns the following resultset:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| shift_hour | shift_day | shift_date | shift_moves | shift_average |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|          7 | Tuesday   | 01/08/2019 |          15 |            11 |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I hope this helps get you moving in the desired direction, @Aron.